# compound nouns word order

Tags: word-usage

When asking about somebody´s eyes? Would you go for " eye colour" or "colour eye". Then if the latter were the more frequently used how would you parapharse it. The former would be "the colour of his-her eyes".In addition, would you use the same structure to refer to hair eg: hair-colour or colour hair.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I correctly form collocations such as "cough trouble"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75388/how-can-i-correctly-form-collocations-such-as-cough-trouble/)

Comment: Another possible question that might help: [Is it correct to say 'word ending games'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103382/is-it-correct-to-say-word-ending-games)

Answer (score 1):

> When asking about somebody´s eyes?

*What is the color of her eyes?*

*What color eyes does she have?*

*What color are her eyes?*

*What is her eye-color?*

All are grammatical, but the last is the least natural; it is how the question might be phrased when someone is filling out a bureaucratic form, like a police robbery report.

If a guy is telling his friend that he has met a nice girl who he thinks is pretty, his friend won't ask him "What is her eye-color?". No, he would ask "What color are her eyes?"

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it would be  "eye color" or "hair color"; that is, the thing which is colored is initial.

English tends to be "head-initial" meaning the head of a phrase precedes complements (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-directionality_parameter). So something meaning "X of Y" is typically "Y X".

Examples:

> I hear birdsong

is equivalent to

> I hear the song of birds

Whereas

> I hear songbirds

means

> I hear birds which sing

Comment: You answer would be more useful if you could provide references to support it. This question merits more than a one-liner.